# How to collapse custom files in Visual Studio 2010, using existent solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio projects, I often use partial classes to extract specific and uniform data, such as database queries or trace IDs, from the code. Example:

```
public partial class GremlinsProvider
{
    public Mogwai GetAMogwai()
    {
        TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Start, TraceId.SearchForMogwai,
            "Querying the database for a Mogwai.");
        var mogwai = new DataQuery(Queries.FindMogwai).ReadRow<Mogwai>();

        TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Stop, TraceId.MogwaiFound, "Found a Mogwai.");
        return mogwai;
    }
}

public partial class GremlinsProvider
{
    private class Queries
    {
        public const FindMogwai = @"
            select top 1
            from [Gremlins]
            where [IsAvailable] = 1 and [PetName] = N'Mogwai'";
    }
}

public partial class GremlinsProvider
{
    private enum TraceId
    {
        SearchForMogwai,
        MogwaiFound,
    }
}
```

In this case, I create three files:

- `GremlinsProvider.cs` which contains the logic,
- `GremlinsProvider.Queries.cs` which contains the constant strings with database queries,
- `GremlinsProvider.Trace.cs` which contains the enumeration of trace IDs.

In Solution Explorer, I want those files to appear collapsed. For example `GremlinsProvider.cs` will expand to contain `GremlinsProvider.Queries.cs` and `GremlinsProvider.Trace.cs` as its children, just like Solution Explorer collapses designer or resources files in a Windows Forms project.

Is it possible to do it **with existent solutions** (i.e. without having to write my own extension), either by configuring Visual Studio 2010 or through an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have no idea what side-effects this may cause!**

From what I can tell, the folding is taken from the `DependentUpon` setting in the `.csproj` file.

As an example, the entry for `GremlinsProvider.Queries.cs` should look like this:

```
<Compile Include="GremlinsProvider.Queries.cs">
  <DependentUpon>GremlinsProvider.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This can be modified at any time during development (no need to create a new project).

If you're wondering whether this can be achieved easier through the IDE, it seems like the answers is [Nope](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/f33c32df-14e4-4636-8c8e-c96f66666cb5/) but there is an extension that promises to do this: [VSCommands](http://vscommands.com/features/) (the feature is called *Group / Ungroup Items*).